# Como usar o método title() no Python?

Tags: python

Como eu uso o **title()** no Python em uma **list, tuple, set**?

```
Exemplos que não executam:

lista = ['banana', 'mamão', 'maçã']
print (lista.title())

tupla = ('banana', 'mamão', 'maçã')
print (tupla.title())

seta = {'banana', 'mamão', 'maçã'}
print (seta.title())
```

Comment: As palavras `list`, `tuple` e `set` são funções internas (built-in function) do Python. Não use estas palavras como variáveis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função `title()` é uma função que está associada a `str` do Python, ou seja, você só consegue usá-la se for em uma *string*. Caso você tenha uma lista de *strings* e queira que cada um da lista seja capitalizada com a função `title`, você tem que percorre a lista e adicionar a função `title` para cada uma deles, isso serve para qualquer interável em Python, como `list`, `set`, `tuple`, etc. Uma maneira simples de se fazer isso sem ter que criar um bloco `for` para percorrer seu interável de *strings* é usando as *comprehensions* do Python, ficaria assim.

```py
lista =['laranja', 'mamão', 'maçã']
nova_lista_captalizada = [ i.title() for i in lista]


tupla = ('banana', 'mamão', 'maçã')
nova_tupla = tuple( i.title() for i in tupla)

# O modo de cima é a mesma coisa que a debaixo
nova_lista_captalizada =[]
for i in lista:
     nova_lista_captalizada.append(i.title())
```

Se você ainda não conhece as *comprehensions* em Python, não tem problema, você precisa entender aqui, que a função `title()`, está relacionada a `str` em Python.

Comment: Não entendi e o código não executa.

Comment: @AlexFeliciano `title` é um método definido na classe `str` e não existe nas classes `list`, `set` e `tuple` como você utilizou na pergunta.

Comment: Oi Robson  - a resposta em "nova tupla" não cria uma tupla - e sim um "generator expression" - um iterador lazy que ger os elementos se for usado num `for` ou com a chamada `next` . Para criar uma tupla é necessário: `nova_tupla = tuple( i.title() for i in tupla)`.  Mas, parabéns pela resposta e explicações como um todo!

Comment: jsbueno, bem observado, é verdade irá retornar generator. Obrigadi pela correção.

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso teria que passar o índice de cada elemento, isso seria a forma "manual" de fazer acontecer e como sabemos em um código robusto torna-se inviável. Estou começando meus estudos e achei interessante comentar já que estou estudando justamente esse tópico.

Exemplo:

motos.py

"""Como uma lista geralmente contém mais de um elemento, é uma boa ideia deixar seu
nome no plural"""

motos = ['honda','yamaha', 'bmw', 'suzuki']
print(motos[0].title())
print(motos[1].title())
print(motos[2].title())
print(motos[3].title())

Answer (score -3):

De maneira simplificada, esse método title() faz com que as strings passem a ter a primeira letra maiúscula.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).